# Universal Analytics events never sent and queue is filling up

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm using Universal Analytics for a single page application, and I track a number of events but they are never sent from the client.

Using the GA Debugger for Chrome, I see that the `ga('send', 'pageview');` is executed, and the very first event is executed. I have verified that the event is showing up in the report, and that the queue is emptied, so this works as expected.

Further on, every event is passed through the ga function using a wrapper I have created:

```
var sendEvent = function(){
    ga.apply(window, ['send', 'event'].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
};
```

The first, working event is also using the wrapper. However, the debugger never shows any of the later hits, and I see that the event queue `ga.q` is filling up.

Am I missing something in order for this to work? Can I trigger GA to send the events in the queue somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out. I had wrapped the code in a closure like this:

```
(function(ga){
  // code
})(ga);
```

I suppose the first event was stored in the GA cache, and when the analytics.js script was loaded, the cache was emptied and the request was sent. Further on, I guess the cache array must have been destroyed, however, the reference to the array was still open within my closure. Thus I was sending events to an array which was no longer handled by GA.

I fixed it by changing the code to reference `window.ga` instead.